# Читабельность кода ветвления на PHP

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Есть один и тот же функционал, реализованный разными инструментами.
Какой вариант, на ваш взгляд проще читать?
На выходе один из вариантов заголовка, зависящий от входных параметров.
На входе 3 параметра:

- $area - площадь (различные заголовки до и более 150);
- $type_deal - тип объявления (продажа и несколько видов аренды);
- $ssid - id-объявления (делим на три группы по признаку остатка от деления на 3, для каждой группы выводим свой заголовок).

#### В1 через ветвление if+switch

```
   if($type_deal == 2) { // Продажа
        if($area > 150) { // Офисный блок
            $title = "Продажа офисного блока ";
        } else { // Офис
            $title = "Продажа офиса ";
        }
    } else { // Аренда
        if($area > 150) { // Офисный блок
            switch($ssid % 3){
                case 0:
                    $title = "Аренда офисного блока ";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $title = "Офисный блок в аренду ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $title = 'Сдается офисный блок ';
                    break;
            }
        } else { // Офис
            switch($ssid % 3){
                case 0:
                    $title = "Аренда офиса ";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $title = "Офис в аренду ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $title = 'Сдается офис ';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### В2 только switch

```
        // type  area  ssid
        // {0-1}_{0-1}_{0-2}
    $title_type = 
        ($type_deal == 2 ? '1' : '0')
        .($area > 150 ? '1' : '0')
        .($ssid % 3);
    switch($title_type){
        // Аренда офиса
        case 000:
            $title = "Аренда офиса ";
            break;
        case 001:
            $title = "Офис в аренду ";
            break;
        case 002:
            $title = 'Сдается офис ';
            break;
        // Аренда офисного блока
        case 010:
            $title = "Аренда офисного блока ";
            break;
        case 011:
            $title = "Офисный блок в аренду ";
            break;
        case 012:
            $title = 'Сдается офисный блок ';
            break;
        // Продажа офиса
        case 100:
        case 101:
        case 102:
            $title = "Продажа офиса ";
            break;
        // Продажа офисного блока
        case 110:
        case 111:
        case 112:
            $title = "Продажа офисного блока ";
            break;
        default:
            $title = false;
    }
```

#### В3 через конструкцию ?:

```
    $title_type = $ssid % 3;
    return $type_deal == 2
        // Продажа
        ?   ($area > 150
            // Офисного блока
            ? "Продажа офисного блока "
            // Офиса
            : "Продажа офиса ")
        // Аренда
        : ($area > 150 
            // Офисный блок
            ? ($title_type == 2 
                // Три вариант заголовка
                ? "Аренда офисного блока "
                : ($title_type == 1 
                    ? "Офисный блок в аренду "
                    : 'Сдается офисный блок '))
            // Офис
            : ($title_type == 2 
                // Три варианта заголовка
                ? "Аренда офиса "
                : ($title_type == 1 
                    ? "Офис в аренду "
                    : 'Сдается офис ')));
```

#### Производительность

Результаты тестирования на большой выборке:

- getName_if = 0.474610090256с
- getName_switch = 1.85297989845с
- getName_tree = 0.482807159424с
- Вытаскивать данные из массива значений (индексы определяются по аналогии с вариантом для switch) = 1.3737449646с

Comment: Я не пхпшник ни разу, но с ходу могу сказать что за третий вариант вам оторвут руки, потому что ассоциативность тернарного оператора в пхп отличается от других языков, (и ни черта не логична по моему мнению =) ). Вложенные тернарники - зло.

Comment: Я бы скомпоновал до `$title=["Аренда офисного блока ", "Офисный блок в аренду ", 'Сдается офисный блок '] [$ssid % 3];` и по аналогии другие части, при желании можно применять ассоциативные массивы

Comment: Имхо 1. Поддерживаю комментарий выше, 3 вариант ужасен, к тому же первый вариант читается гораздо проще.

Comment: не один из вариантов @Mike к стати дельный совет дал на счёт ассоциативного массива.

Comment: @Mike, почему не ответом? :)

Comment: Как по мне дак манипулирования и редактирования подобных строк в пхп коде вообще не должно быть. Конструируйте какую нибудь строку идентификатора, и используйте единый файл локализаций для сопоставления с нормальными названиями. Если такая шляпа будет встречаться в разных местах проекта, то это треш какой-то.

Comment: это я к примеру про [po-файлы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) делайте файл локализаций с идентификатором по вашему шаблону `msgid some.prefix.type_areaGroup_sid` и строку локализации сообщения  `msgstr` в коде простой конструкцией генерируете строку идентификатора, а в представлении выводите локализованный вариант. Ваш код будет состоять из 5 строк, а все локализации будут вынесены в один файл.

Comment: во втором варианте надо к значениями `case` добавить кавычки. Целочисленные литералы, начинающиеся с 0 php считает в восьмеричной системе, поэтому строка "010" не будет равна числу 010

Answer (score 1):

Я бы слегка модифицировал 2й вариант, и получилось бы очень красиво, форматирование, все дела, шо хошь. Единственный минус - весь функционал, это возвращение какого-либо значения. В случаях с кейсами, или ифами можно дополнительно хендлить события еще, но если задача стоит *только* в выводе, я бы предпочел это:

```
    // type  area  ssid
    // {0-1}_{0-1}_{0-2}
$title_type = 
    ($type_deal == 2 ? '1' : '0')
    .($area > 150 ? '1' : '0')
    .($ssid % 3);
$titles = Array(
    '001' => 'Офис в аренду ',
    '002' => 'Офис на продажу',
    ... => '...',
   '1337' => 'куплю гараж'
);
$title = $titles[$title_type];
```

Емнип, самый быстрый вывод, по индексированному массиву.

Comment: По массиву не самый быстрый вывод из-за подсчета индексов. В конце поста приведено время исполнения для варианта с ассоциативным многомерным массивом на 1 000 000 испытаний.

Comment: @Saty, как *"проще читать"* из вопроса коррелирует с этими вашими бенчмарками?